# How to disable magnifier of product image on mobile devices in magento2?

Tags: magento2, product-images, product-view, zoom, mobile-device

I want to make `magnifier` disable in mobile device, I have tried below code in `view.xml` file but not working in **mobile devices**.

```
<var name="breakpoints">
        <var name="mobile">
            <var name="conditions">
                <var name="max-width">767px</var>
            </var>                
            <var name="magnifier">
                <var name="enabled">false</var>
            </var>
        </var>
</var>
```

When i tap on product image in **mobile devices** page get blank.

Answer (score 1):

Create a view.xml file if you havent allready in app\design\frontend\YOUR_VENDOR\base\etc\view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd">
    <vars module="Magento_Catalog">
        <var name="breakpoints">
            <var name="mobile">
                <var name="conditions">
                    <var name="max-width">767px</var>
                </var>
                <var name="options">
                    <var name="options">
                        <var name="allowfullscreen">false</var>
                    </var>

                </var>
            </var>
        </var>
    </vars>
</view>
```

allowfullscreen enables or disables magnifier

Tested on magento 2.3 EE

Comment: This solution is working, thank you very much!